# guzzle POST returns an empty body

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using such structure of request

```
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://api.brain.com.ua/']);
        $request = new Request('POST', 'auth', [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Accept-Language' => 'ru,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => '1',

            ],

            'form_params' => ['login' => $this->login, 'password' =>md5($this->password)]]);
        $response = $client->send($request, ['timeout' => 2]);
```

server returnns 200

but method $response->getBody() returns an empty result
while the cURL returns normal answer {"status":1,"result":"gpkavk4s0aciujg6m698gev040"}

how can i get the same result using GuzzleHttp ?

Comment: I think you have to increase timeout limit  `'timeout' => 2`. check how much time curl take to response and provide that much time here

Comment: It seems due to very less timeout Your execution terminated before getting response.

Comment: thank you, thats helped me  $client = new Client();
                $response = $client->post($this->url, ['form_params' => ['login' => $this->login, 'password' =>md5($this->password)]]);
                $output = $response->getBody()->getContents();